# How to call function defined using jquery in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is sample jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('#myId').change(function(){
      regularJSfunc('data1','data2');
    });

}
```

now i want to trigger function call of  $('#myId').change  , can i do it through java script ?

Comment: yes, you can do that, but if you want an example you have to tell us what '#myId' is.

Comment: You forgot to close you document ready, last line should be }); vs }.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/c4QcW/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery actually provides a way for you to do that:

```
$("#myId").trigger("change");
```

Or you could chain it only the code you already have to call it immediately:

```
$("#myId").on("change", function(){
  regularJSfunc( 'data1', 'data2' );
}).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using trigger call this function immediately on load script. So better use [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/):

```
$('#myId').bind('change', function(){
    regularJSfunc( 'data1', 'data2' );
});

$('#myId').triggerHandler('change'); //call function
```